# How to display sevral pieces of data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys what i am looking for is to display lots of data on 1 page so instead of using hundreds of pages with all different data how can i use one page to display multiple pieces of data using php and mysql i will give an example

If a user requests to see GTA IV the url would be mysite.com/index.php?PID=00001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember giving you the below answer, the last time you asked..

... Assuming, `$employee` is a fetch data from mysql..

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['PID'])) {

$employee = array('nina','simon','tom','zannel','bob');
foreach($employee as $key=>$e) {

if($key == $_GET['PID']) {
echo 'PID: '.$_GET['PID'].' Name: '.$e.' PHONE No: '.'00'.$key; }
    }
 }else {
echo 'Id is not found';

}
```

This is how it will display:

if you typed URL `index.php?PID=1`

> PID: 1 Name: simon PHONE No: 001

if you typed URL `index.php?PID=2`

> PID: 2 Name: Tom PHONE No: 002

if you typed URL `index.php?PID=2`

> PID: 3 Name: zannel PHONE No: 003

Comment: Thankyou i appreciate your feed back i tried your script last night but .$_GET['PID'].' Name: '.$e.' PHONE No: '.'00'.$key; } how would i add multiple pices of data like  discription price name image url ect? im no good with php im just starting to learn about it

Comment: You can play around with the script. I said, `$employee` is a row, which holds data of employee's names, similarly, you can store data of description, and do a query to output the data

Comment: okay thankyou for your advice i will have a play around thank you